# Categories not shown on sidebar

Tags: php, css, wordpress, html

SO far I've made 2 categories for my web in **wordpress**  and yet  I just have 1 in sidebar. how should I do to show all the categories on sidebar?

[image: home]

[image: when i go to a page that has House categories]

Comment: If categories don't have any post then categories will not display in sidebar.

Comment: drag category widget to the corresponding sidebar.

Comment: This question belongs on https://wordpress.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I think i don't use any widget

Comment: It has post each category.. I don't know what's wrong